# Universal Telegram Bot library doesn't work with Arduino nano 33 iot but it doesn't show an error

Tags: arduino, telegram-bot, iot

I've tried for the first time the example echobot using an arduino nano 33 iot and the classical arduino ide.
I have created a bot using botfather.
I have uploaded the code of the example on the board.
The serial monitor tells me that it's connected to the wifi and shows me the SSID the IP address and the signal strenght but when I try to write something using the telegram bot, nothing happens: I don't receive the echo message in the bot chat.
Can anybody help me?

This is the code:

```
/*******************************************************************
    A telegram bot for your WifiNINA devices that responds
    with whatever message you send it.

    Parts:
    Arduino Nano 33 IOT - https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano-33-iot

    If you find what I do useful and would like to support me,
    please consider becoming a sponsor on Github
    https://github.com/sponsors/witnessmenow/


    Written by Brian Lough
    YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/brianlough
    Tindie: https://www.tindie.com/stores/brianlough/
    Twitter: https://twitter.com/witnessmenow
 *******************************************************************/

// ----------------------------
// Standard Libraries
// ----------------------------
#include <SPI.h>

// ----------------------------
// Additional Libraries - each one of these will need to be installed.
// ----------------------------
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
// Library for using network deatures of the official Arudino
// Wifi Boards (MKR WiFi 1010, Nano 33 IOT etc)

// Search for "nina" in the Arduino Library Manager
// https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFiNINA

#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
// Library for connecting to Telegram

// Search for "Telegram" in the Arduino Library Manager
// Install the "Universal Telegram" one by Brian Lough
// https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot

#include <ArduinoJson.h>
// Library used for parsing Json from the API responses

// Search for "Arduino Json" in the Arduino Library manager
// https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

// Wifi network station credentials
char ssid[] = "SSID";         // your network SSID (name)
char password[] = "password"; // your network password
// Telegram BOT Token (Get from Botfather)
#define BOT_TOKEN "XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

const unsigned long BOT_MTBS = 1000; // mean time between scan messages

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiSSLClient client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOT_TOKEN, client);
unsigned long bot_lasttime; // last time messages' scan has been done

void handleNewMessages(int numNewMessages)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numNewMessages; i++)
  {
    bot.sendMessage(bot.messages[i].chat_id, bot.messages[i].text, "");
  }
}

void printWiFiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void setup()
{
    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWiFiStatus();
}

void loop()
{
  if (millis() - bot_lasttime > BOT_MTBS)
  {
    int numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);

    while (numNewMessages)
    {
      Serial.println("got response");
      handleNewMessages(numNewMessages);
      numNewMessages = bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1);
    }

    bot_lasttime = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Telegram root certificate to the Wifi Module.
Use the **Wifi101/WifiNINA Firmware updater**.

Refer here

https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360016119219-How-to-add-certificates-to-Wifi-Nina-Wifi-101-Modules-